# Example of a ring satisfying this variant definition of "symmetric" on nilpotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want an example to show that if $a,b$ are nilpotent elements of a ring $R$ with 1 and if $c$ is any element of $R$, then $abc=0\Rightarrow acb=0$ but $cab=0$ does not imply $acb=0$.

This is unlike symmetric ring, where we know that if $a,b,c\in R$ and $abc=0$ implies that $acb=0$.

Please help me to find a ring where to search for an example or help me to show that if $abc=0 \Rightarrow acb=0$, then $cab=0 \Rightarrow acb=0$ for all nilpotent elements $a,b$ in $R$ and for all $c\in R$.

Cross-posted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144485/example-of-a-ring-satisfying-this-variant-definition-of-symmetric-on-nilpotent

Comment: Hi: I changed your title because it suggested you were looking for a special symmetric ring, but (as you noted in the body) no symmetric ring would be an example.

Comment: Where does this question come from? It sounds a little like something homemade, but of course I could be wrong :) Please let us know.

Comment: @ rschwieb, yes you are right. This question is homemade. I tried to define such ring, but couldn't be able to show that this types of rings are not right-left symmetric, though I have strong intuition that this is so.

Comment: If you do not know if your question has a definite answer, you should say so in your post. Otherwise someone might waste a lot of time on it and be annoyed when you tell them later. If you warn them though, they'll know what they're getting themselves into :)

Comment: Thanks...I am changing the question a bit

Comment: I don't think you want to say "for above mentioned $a,b,c$".

Comment: @darij grinberg: I think now it's alright.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki solution designed to remove this item from the unanswered queue.*

---

**Edit:** The question has received [an answer at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/144512/19965), which looks correct to me -- Todd Trimble.